# Declare a user defined distribution

Tags: r, distribution, declaration

How do you define your own distributions in R?  If I have a distribution that looks something like this:

```
P(D=0)=2/4, P(D=1)=1/4, P(D=2)=1/4
```

How do I turn that into a distribution I can work with?

In the end, I want to be able to use these and do things involving cdfs, icdfs and pmfs. Like find the probability of 1 through a cdf type thing. And I also need to find out how to graph things. But I was going to ask in smaller steps and try to figure things out in between.

Comment: You'll probably want to clarify what you mean by "work with".  Do you want the pmf? CDF? quantiles? Just random draws from the distribution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you just need to generate random variates from the distribution, this should suffice:

```
rMydist <- function(n) {
    sample(x = c(0,1,2), size = n, 
           prob = c(.5, .25, .25), replace=T)
}

rMydist(20)
# [1] 1 0 2 0 2 1 1 0 2 2 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 1

prop.table(table(rMydist(1e6)))
#        0        1        2 
# 0.500555 0.250044 0.249401
```

For something more fancy, try out the **distr** package. In addition to random number generation, it'll get you the density, distribution, and quantile functions associated with your distribution:

```
library(distr)
## For more info, type: vignette("newDistributions")  

# Define full suite of functions (d*, p*, q*, r*) for your distribution
D <- DiscreteDistribution (supp = c(0, 1, 2) , prob = c(0.5, .25, .25))
dD <- d(D)  ## Density function
pD <- p(D)  ## Distribution function
qD <- q(D)  ## Quantile function
rD <- r(D)  ## Random number generation

# Take them for a spin
dD(-1:3)
# [1] 0.00 0.50 0.25 0.25 0.00
pD(-1:3)
# [1] 0.00 0.50 0.75 1.00 1.00
qD(seq(0,1,by=0.1))
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 2
rD(20)
# [1] 0 0 2 2 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 2 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks :) that helps, I need to do more than get random numbers but that helped a lot.